# Go Module : main.go file is being overwritten after go build

Tags: go, build, dependencies, go-modules

I am facing an weird issue where after vendorising my dependencies with go modules, go build command is overriding the main.go file with random data.

Start of the file looks like this:

```
����
H
H__PAGEZEROx__TEXTpxpx__text__TEXT��7�__rodata__TEXT��7Y��7__symbol_stub1__TEXT�V��V�__typelink__TEXT�V�(�V__itablink__TEXTP@V�
P@V__gosymtab__TEXT�JV�JV__gopclntab__TEXTKV
"KV�__DATApx�|px c
__nl_symbol_ptr__DATApx�pxs__noptrdata__DATA�sx���sx__data__DATA�&{���&{__bss__DATA �{��__noptrbss__DATA�}�2__DWARF�}�{��   __zdebug_abbrev__DWARF�}�{__zdebug_line__DWARF�}'W�{__zdebug_frame__DWARF;H���;8�__zdebug_pubname__DWARF�څ�K�ʃ__zdebug_pubtype__DWARF�&����__debug_gdb_scri__DWARF��6�ӄ__zdebug_info__DWARF���
�ӄ__zdebug_loc__DWARF䉑��y�__zdebug_ranges__DWARFU��ZE�H__LINKEDIT�}L���L��*�����,�r���Pu,u,x,xo�� /usr/lib/dyld8/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylibh/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation`/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security$

� Go build ID: "OLftMbjtv5aWMkI_0qrD/LhWRtD0wcaKFWRYSDOa9/7dFWcNOQ4BpWWqZQW07D/pkR9ABiz-SHIBaJIZ1ur"
 ����������UH��AWAVATSH���=|I��
```

Go version: go version `go1.12.5 darwin/amd64`

Enabled Go moduled with `export GO111MODULE=on`

Folder structure:
go.mod  go.sum  log.go  main.go vendor

FYI: only main.go is being overwritten, not log.go.

Go module initialised with `go mod init`

App vendorised with `go mod vendor`

Not sure if I am doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What commands do you use exactly? Did you maybe name your module `main.go`?

Comment: Thanks @JimB. This is the issue. I just ran `go mod init` and it created the module with name `main.go`. Running `go build` is then overriding the `main.go` file. Changing the module name to main (or anything other than main.go) solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The module name should not be main.go as it is a file inside a package. Please use your project name for module name in `go mod init`.

For example, if your project root is hello, name your package hello, not `main.go`.
Also if you want to use the module over and over again, please consider using your repository name as the module name.

Go handles packages not individual files. Go modules are used to organize packages. Know more in [official documentation](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)